# Missing 'Ajax' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web.Mvc'

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying out examples from a book.  The first one is really simple .. a few lines of code in a view (MVC).

I run the code but get an error :

Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Ajax' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web.Mvc' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

```
Source Error:


Line 22:     using System.Web.WebPages;
Line 23:     using System.Web.Mvc;
Line 24:     using System.Web.Mvc.Ajax;
Line 25:     using System.Web.Mvc.Html;
Line 26:     using System.Web.Routing;

Source File: c:\Users\Aindriu\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6882868f\b519e811\App_Web_index.cshtml.a8d08dba.h-o4pos5.0.cs    Line: 24
```

I fixed the problem - I right clicked the solution in Solution Properties (on the right) and selected Manage Nuget Packages - i typed in MVC on top right search bar - and installed MVC.... it installed a whole load of files and my program worked..... but it added code to the solution I am working on..

Is there a easy way to get around this error ? I don't want to have to keep doing this every time I create a MVC program...

Comment: Visual Studio version? MVC version?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate.  MVC is 4.5.1

Comment: And what version of MVC is the book about?

Comment: Also, make sure you have the correct assembly referenced. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxextensions%28v=vs.118%29.aspx.

Comment: how do I reference the correct assembly ? Is there not a way that I can install MVC permanently ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With newer versions of MVC, the preferred method is to use the NuGet package manager. Under: *View > Other Windows > Package Manager Console*. Type:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc -Version 4.5.1
```

You should do this for every Mvc project.

Comment: thanks for the reply ! Just a question... do I need to add the MVC packages (like above or via  Manage Nuget Packages) every time I create a new MVC solution ? thanks

Comment: Yes, you need to add dependencies every time you create a new solution. The cool thing is every solution has its own set of dependencies so everything Just Works when you deploy to Windows Server. No need to tinker with Windows Install or the base server build.

Comment: I am having some trouble.. I have loaded another sample exercise and it is throwing up an error : Compiler Error Message: CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Ajax' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web.Mvc' (are you missing an assembly reference?) ... I tried adding MVC like I did before but its not working... I read to try changing set System.Web.Mvc property "Copy Local" to true but I can't see where

Answer (score 7):

If you are using Visual Studio, from the project's *References* select the *System.Web.Mvc* dll. At the *Properties Window* set the *Copy Local* attribute to *True*.

You could even copy the necessary references to the *bin\Debug* or *bin\Release* directory (whichever you would use) manually, but setting it to happen automatically by Visual Studio is far better.